# angela22 - 419 scammer on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, users, moderators

User [angela22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284442/angela22) is answering questions with your typical "lots of money to extract from" style 419 scam. I've flagged a couple of the answers, but thought it would be easier to highlight the user instead.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a user angela bila posting now

Comment: Thanks, that's clearly the same person.  Status: terminated. ;)

Comment: @Bill: I didn't know you supported the death penalty!

Comment: @Andrew: If only it was that easy...

Answer (score 1):

Here's Angela Bila's message:

FROM: ANGELA BILA, ABIDJAN, COTE D'IVOIRE. [removed]

DEAREST ONE IN CHRIST,

MAY THE GRACE OF ALMIGHTY GOD BE WITH YOU FOREVER. AMEN

I AM ANGELA BILA , 23 YEARS OLD FROM ABIDJAN - COTE D'IVOIRE. I AM THE ONLY DAUGHTER OF LATE MR AND MRS JOSEPH BILA, WHO WAS A VERY WEALTHY AND PROMINENT AGRICULTURAL PRODUCTS DEALER BASED IN ABIDJAN, THE ECONOMIC CAPITAL OF COTE D'IVOIRE.

I HAD A HUGE SUM OF MONEY US$12,500,000.00 MILLIONS USA DOLLARS (TWELVE MILLION AND FIVE HUNDRED THOUSAND USA DOLLARS) WHICH I INHERITED FROM MY LATE FATHER AS THE ONLY DAUGHTER OF MY LATE PARENT AND THIS FUNDS IS DEPOSITED BY MY LATE FATHER IN ONE OF THE MAJOR BANKS HERE IN THE CITY BEFORE HIS SUDDEN DEATH. MY MOTHER DIED WHEN I WAS TWO YEARS OLD AND I WAS SPECIAL TO THEM.

AS A MATTER OF URGENCY I NEED A FOREIGN ACCOUNT AND PERSONALITY WHO WILL HELP ME OUT TO TRANSFER THIS FUNDS INTO HIS / HER BANK ACCOUNT IN HIS COUNTRY. NATIONALITY OF ORIGIN NOT IMPORTANT.

I WILL OFFER THE FORTUNATE HELPER WITH 25% FOR EVERY ASSISTANCE HE/ SHE WILL RENDER TO ME. ALSO I WILL LIKE YOU TO HELP ME INVEST THIS FUNDS INTO A LUCRATIVE BUSINESS VENTURES THAT WILL FETCH US HUGE PROFITS FOR THE REST OF OUR LIVES. AND I WILL ALSO USE SOME PART OF THE MONEY TO WORK FOR GOD, SUCH AS BUILDING CHURCHES FOR GOD AND EVANGELIZING FOR HIM. BUT NOT ALL, BECAUSE I WILL USE SOME PART FOR MAKING STRONG BUSINESS INVESTMENTS IN YOUR COUNTRY. CONTACT ME NOW SO THAT I WILL FLUSH YOU UP WITH ALL THE VITAL INFORMATION RELATING TO THE DEPOSITED MONEY AND THE TRANSACTION.

KINDLY CONTACT ME IMMEDIATELY NOW FOR MORE DETAILS ON MY PERSONAL EMAIL ADDRESS BELOW AND MY PHONE NUMBER:

MY EMAIL : [removed]@yahoo.fr & : [removed]@yahoo.fr TEL : [removed]

THANKS AND REMAIN BLESS.

ANGELA BILA. [removed]

Comment: And how is this any different from this???(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40585/free-laptop-to-deserving-meta-user-complete)

Comment: Dear Angela, *Waffles.*  Best regards, Pollyanna

Comment: @heavyd, I'm sure Jeff actually sent the laptop

Comment: If she offered waffles, she'd get so much more responses...

Comment: @Downvoter: Why'd you remove her email address? Now how am I supposed to help her? You just want to keep the money for yourself don't you!

Comment: Angela is not only equipped with $12.5 million in cash, she is also young and hot.

Comment: WHAT, IM SORRY, I CANT HEAR YOU?

Comment: @JeffAtwood ,we are facing the same thing in artificial intelligence community.scammers and fake accounts.